# Refresh TextBlock quicker from another thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, data-binding

I do have a WPF application displaying data (computed from another thread) in real-time. But my UI components (here a `TextBlock`) update very slowly.
I use traditional data binding with `PropertyChanged` notifications.
xaml :

```
<TextBlock
          Foreground="DarkGray"
          Text="{Binding Path=ContactSurface, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00} cm²'}"/>
```

code-behind (no, this is not MVVM, shame on me) :

```
private double _contactSurface;
    public double ContactSurface
    {
        get { return _contactSurface; }
        set { _contactSurface = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ContactSurface"); }
    }

    public void Compute() // external thread about 10 Hz
    {
        ContactSurface = (double)nbSensorsNotNulls * DataSource.SensorSurface * 0.01;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { })); // does not change a thing
        //Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { })); // crash : Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.

        //UpdateLayout(); // crash : The calling thread can not access this object because a different thread owns it
        //InvalidateVisual(); // crash : The calling thread can not access this object because a different thread owns it

    }
```

I've tried some things I've found around the web at the end of `Compute()` with very mean results detailes

Comment: Maybe you should put ContactSurface = (double)nbSensorsNotNulls * DataSource.SensorSurface * 0.01 inside Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: That seems to work ! I'm not sure what was the problem. Maybe RaisePropertyChanged() did not synchronise from Compute thread so the dispatcher was not aware that ContactSurface changed. Thax a lot !!!

Comment: There is a inconvenient with this method : it tends to freeze the UI. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your execute some time-consuming work in another thread, then you **must** synchronize a result of another thread with UI thread. To synchronize two threads(new thread and UI thread), it is necessary to use **[Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Only one thread can modify the UI thread. But how do background threads interact
>   with the user? A background thread can ask the UI thread to perform an
>   operation on its behalf. It does this by registering a work item with
>   the Dispatcher of the UI thread. The Dispatcher class provides two
>   methods for registering work items: Invoke and BeginInvoke. Both
>   methods schedule a delegate for execution. Invoke is a synchronous
>   call – that is, it doesn’t return until the UI thread actually
>   finishes executing the delegate. BeginInvoke is asynchronous and
>   returns immediately.

For example:

```
Task.Run(()=> {
   var result = (double)nbSensorsNotNulls * DataSource.SensorSurface * 0.01;
   Thread.Sleep(5000);//imitate time consuming work
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
            new Action(() => { 
                            ContactSurface=result;}));
});
```

In the above example, we create a new thread(`Task.Run(...)`) and synchronize result of new thread with UI thread(`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`)

Comment: Thx, this is even better because there is less computation inside the Action(). My UI may freeze a little now. I suppose I have to limite Dispatcher computation and mb frequency of Dispatcher calls ?

Comment: @olivier you are right! you should just insert **result of non-UI thread** into Dispatcher. Please, read this article and you will get very useful knowledges: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx